# Servlet deployment structure different in eclipse

Tags: java

In a basic servlet example , inside WEB-INF we should put all java classes  & lib of jar files. But in eclipse , I found in one of the project, these java classes are not inside WEB-INF . Why this is so ? & How this structure getting deployed properly in tomcat ?

Comment: Because in eclipse the java files from src folders are not compiled yet. When you will export it to a war file it will be compiled and will be present in WEB-INF folder

Comment: Thank u for Ur info.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment is controlled by the options on the 'deployment assembly' settings of the project's properties.  It can take the binaries (the .class files) from any location you have configured as the compilation's output folder.  It will also include prerequisite projects and/or libraries per your specifications on that tab.

Comment: Why eclipse by default gives that feature ? yes after opening the project deployment structure in tomcat home folder , I can see inside web inf all classes r there .

Comment: What do you mean "why does eclipse provide that feature" ?  What feature are you talking about ?  Running on a servlet container implies deploying to a servlet container. Do you not want that to be configurable for your specific setup of [development level] servlet containers ?  Do you think everbody has *exactly* the same requirements or desiderata in that area ?  One, some might want to test on glassfish instead of tomcat.  Two, deploying to an "external" installed tomcat version may run into security issues so a "localized" container instance is needed.  etc. etc.